# Как удалить определенный тег без id или class'a из html с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<h3>Text 1</h3>'
<h3>Text 2</h3>
<h3>Text 3</h3>
```

Есть 3 тега без id или class'a, нужно по нажатию на пример тег с текстом **Text 2** удалить иммено этот тег. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить на этот тег обработчик, внутри которого удалить сам элемент.

Добавлять обработчики можно с помощью [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), либо [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) в случае jQuery.

В самом обработчике `this` будет указывать на нужный элемент.

Удалить элемент можно следующими способами:

1. [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)  для новых браузеров: `this.remove()`
2. [`.parentNode.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) для старых браузеров: `this.parentNode.removeChild(this)`
3. [`.remove` из jQuery](http://%60.remove%60%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20jQuery): `$(this).remove()`